# How can we automatically center different SVG path into their viewports?

Tags: html, svg

We allow our users to upload their own SVG icons as SVG Path in our backoffice admin, so that we can use these path in touch applications in different languages (we can thus colorise the path, fill it or not according to interaction). (So no, we can't use PNGs).

Now we are trying to render the path in a web view so that we can list the existing icons.
But path are totally different from one to another, with coordinates sometimes starting to 0,0, sometimes from the center of the canvas (usually created under Illustrator) so we have icons of different size and different alignments.

- Some are small and start from 0,0
- Some are wide and start from 500,200

Sample:
[small icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3m8U.jpg) --- [Big icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWSlb.jpg)

and  I need them all to be set into a square, centered, same size (which should be possible, they're only vector after all)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuA49.jpg)

I tried to manipulate the viewport coordinates, but it's really empirical, I Don't really understand what I'm doing (just changing pan and zoom until it works), but it depends on each icon, and I need to find a solution for all icons.
Then I tried another way with background (which seemed a very nice trick)

I set the SVG path as a Background, and try to center the image. It worked ! (unexpectedly)
But it works only for icon bigger than the viewport. If the icon is a small one, it just keeps standing up left.
here are my 5 tests

https://codepen.io/XavDeb/pen/zQPZXz

HTML

```
    <!-- background test 2 -->
    <div class="float">background test glass plate <br>
      <div id="background2">2 </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
svg {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  border:solid black;
}
#background2 {
  width : 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border : solid 1px blue;
  background-image : url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 100"><path d="M 323.423,59.2223L 319.407,59.2223C 318.136,59.2223 317.157,58.1303 317.279,56.8649C 317.655,52.9329 317.249,43.9009 309.957,28.4276C 309.661,27.8009 310.431,27.2089 310.945,27.6743C 315.561,31.8516 325.4,45.3969 325.06,54.3369C 325.06,57.8969 325.061,56.3969 325.063,57.5876C 325.064,58.4943 324.329,59.2223 323.423,59.2223 Z M 303.227,16.2969C 300.342,15.7223 297.363,15.4169 294.309,15.4169C 291.14,15.4169 288.047,15.7436 285.06,16.3623L 285.06,7.25027C 285.06,6.2116 285.937,5.33294 286.976,5.33294L 301.309,5.33294C 302.349,5.33294 303.227,6.2116 303.227,7.25027M 343.393,57.8329L 339.617,57.8329C 338.391,39.0489 325.751,23.3889 308.56,17.7103L 308.56,7.25027C 308.56,3.26227 305.297,-0.000396729 301.309,-0.000396729L 286.976,-0.000396729C 282.989,-0.000396729 279.727,3.26227 279.727,7.25027L 279.727,17.8236C 262.705,23.5929 250.221,39.1716 249.003,57.8329L 245.393,57.8329C 243.193,57.8329 241.393,59.6329 241.393,61.8329C 241.393,64.0329 243.193,65.8329 245.393,65.8329L 343.393,65.8329C 345.593,65.8329 347.393,64.0329 347.393,61.8329C 347.393,59.6329 345.593,57.8329 343.393,57.8329 Z" ></path></svg>');

  background-repeat : repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color :green;
  background-size : cover;

}
```

This almost works, but the same code with a small icon doesn't work at all.

Is there any way to success what I'm trying to do ?
(or should I just repath all the icons)

Comment: my greeting is wipped away ??

Comment: I'd probably just do something [like this](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/jLOgVz) personally, but it is a pretty broad issue if the path data isn't clean.

Comment: I'm not si sure about this way of creating SVG. I have a vector path, but you use here some strange javascript geometry as array.
I'm not sure I can convert a SVG path into a geometry array...

Comment: SVG Path **is** a geometry array delimited by commas and markers like `L`, `M`, `Z` etc, but glad you found a remedy either way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the methods you are using in that CodePen (eg `background-image`) can't really be modified at runtime to automatically scale your SVGs.

But for inline SVGs, you can do something like this:

```
var PADDING = 0.2;  // 20% padding on all sides
var svgElements = document.querySelectorAll('.float > svg'); 
svgElements.forEach(function(svg) {
  var bbox = svg.getBBox();
  var padX = PADDING * bbox.width;
  var padY = PADDING * bbox.height;
  var viewbox = [bbox.x - padX, bbox.y - padY,
                 bbox.width + 2*padX, bbox.height + 2*padY].join(' ');
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', viewbox);
});
```

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/ZNvzzp

It should work for most well crafted SVGs.  But it can't automatically fix bad SVGs. Like your last two. Which seem to have bad `<pattern>` definitions.

Comment: Oh so you're using getbbox jvascript method.
I tried this without succeedig. 
Thanks a lot, I think it's the only way...

Comment: tested with various icons and working.

 Thanks, that was a great solution (though I hoped we could do it without javascript)

https://codepen.io/XavDeb/pen/zQPZXz